# My Node.js not sending mails after uploading it to Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I have made a website using Node.js which will send mail when it is triggered. It was working fine while running it on my localhost. I deployed it to Heroku and my website is working fine but mails are not being sent.

I even turned on the access to low-secure-apps also.

Comment: Please, try to give more clues about your issue, show some relevant code about the mail part and some logs about the error, otherwise is impossible to help you.

Comment: https://medium.com/@.jay/sending-email-using-express-js-with-nodemailer-in-heroku-71741f29 refer this.... I guess you have issues regarding Imap

Answer (score 1):

> I even turned on the access to low-secure-apps also

I guess you're talking about Gmail here, since there's a "less secure apps" feature in Gmail?

Gmail is designed for interactive, personal use, not for programmatic use. I *strongly* urge you to switch to a service that's better suited to this task like SendGrid or Mailgun. [Heroku addons exist for these, and other, email providers](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/#email-sms).